# error changing font in matplotlib python in windows 10

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this issue:
I wanted to change the font and fontsize in matplotlib but now I have an error message:

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1331: 
UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['sans-serif'] not found. Falling back to 
DejaVu Sans
(prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))
```

I saw `$ sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts -qq` being used as a solution in other forums, but it seems like that's for ubuntu. (I'm a complete newbie) I'm lost - I am not using Linux, I am using Windows 10 trying to work through a Kaggle kernel. How do I fix this error? And in addition, how do I properly change font style in matplotlib?
 
Thank you for your help in advance :)

Comment: Try to rebuild font cache of matplotlib calling `matplotlib.font_manager._rebuild()` in the head of your script.

Comment: First of all it would be useful to know *how* you tried to change the font.